# The proof of SVD solver formula, $C^T C = V \Sigma^T \Sigma V^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

This formula could be used to compute `matrix multiplication transpose`

$${\displaystyle (\mathbf {AB} )^{\mathsf {T}}=\mathbf {B} ^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {A} ^{\mathsf {T}}}$$

This formula is used to elaborate `matrix multiplication associativity`

$${\displaystyle (\mathbf {AB} )\mathbf {C} =\mathbf {A} (\mathbf {BC} )}$$

This formula is used to compute svd of a matrix.

$$C = U \Sigma V^T$$

this [MIT course](https://youtu.be/Yw1xmxPH_ps?t=113) puts them together and gives (equation_1)

$$C^T C = V \Sigma^T \Sigma V^T \tag 1$$

what is the detailed proof for equation_1?

first, what is the detailed procedure of $C^TC = (U \Sigma V^T)^TC$

how can I transfer this to $U^TU$?

$$C^T = V \Sigma^T U^T$$

Comment: $U$ is real orthogonal. Thus $U^TU=I$.

Comment: Remember, $U$ is chosen to be such that $U^T U = I$ (identity matrix). Using this and your first two equations, you should be able to prove the result. (Note that with associativity, you can compute any two adjacent matrices' product first, and with the transpose rule, it extends to multiple matrices: $$(ABC\ldots XYZ)^T = Z^TY^T X^T \ldots C^T B^T A^T.$$)

Comment: You haven’t numbered your equations. Which one is “equation_1?” (Use `\tag` to number them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your first two equations, you can get

$$(ABC)^T = ((AB)C)^T = C^T(AB)^T = C^T B^T A^T$$

and then

$$C^T = V \Sigma^T U^T$$

and then

$$C^T C = V \Sigma^T U^T C = V \Sigma^T U^T U \Sigma V^T$$

since

$$U^TU = I$$

eventually you get

$$C^T C = V \Sigma^T U^T U \Sigma V^T = V \Sigma^T \Sigma V^T$$